# Android tests with Gradle: Change JUnit test output file name

Tags: android, junit, gradle, report, filenames

When I run JUnit tests for my Android project with Gradle (via tasks androidTest or connectedAndroidTest) I get an automatically generated output XML file with test-results under 'build/outputs/androidTest-results/connected'. This file is always called something like 'TEST-NexusS_Android16(AVD) - 4.1.2-app-.xml', depending on the device or emulator I run the tests on.

I would like to change the filename to something more generic, like 'junit-test-report.xml' (for being able to parse it with Jenkins JUnit plugin without setting a specific filename for every device).

From http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Test-reports I know that I can set the output folder by putting

```
testOptions {
  reportDir = "$project.buildDir/foo/report"
}
```

in my Gradle build-file.

I think, it must be possible to change the filename, too? Couldn't find anything about that on the web.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Did you find a solution?